# Argument of type '{ data: DocumentData; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<emailType[]>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

am trying to add and also get the document am getting from the firebase database using TypeScript but am getting error Argument of type '{ data: DocumentData; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<emailType[]>'. is working when am trying any type but I want to be able to destructure it when mapping the emails. please how can I get it done.

Here's my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { collection, addDoc, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore'

export type MailRowType = {
  recipients: string,
  subject: string,
  description: string,
  time: number | Symbol,
}

export type emailType = {
  data:MailRowType,
  id: string
}

const Inbox = () => {
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState<emailType[]>([])
  const {compose, setCompose, composeDropDown, setComposeDropDown} = useContextState()
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = async (data:any): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "emails"), {
        recipients: data.recipients || null,
        subject: data.subject || null,
        description: data.description || null,
        time: Timestamp || null,
      });
      console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
    }
    setCompose(false)
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCities(db:any) {
      const citiesCol = collection(db, 'emails');
      const citySnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol); 
      if (citySnapshot) {
        setEmails(citySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          data: doc.data(),
      })))
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
      
    }
    getCities(db)
  },[])

return (
    <div  className='inbox'>{emails.map((data:{description, recipients, subject, time}:MailRowType, {id}:string) => (
          <MailRow key={id} recipients={recipients} time={time} subject={subject} description={description}/>
      ))}
</div>
```

// mailrow file

```
import {MailRowType } from "../pages/Inbox"
const MailRow = (data:MailRowType, id:string) => {

  return (
    <div className='mailrow'>
 
       <h2>{data.recipients}</h2>      
       <h4>{data.subject}</h4>
       <p>{data.description}</p>
       <span>{time}</span>
    </div>
)
}

export default MailRow
```

Answer (score 0):

the correct type has not been passed.

here is the solution code.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { collection, addDoc, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"; 
import { Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore'

export type MailRowType = {
  recipients: string,
  subject: string,
  description: string,
  time: number | Symbol,
}

export type dataBaseType = {
  data:MailRowType,
  id: string
}

const Inbox = () => {
  const [emails, setEmails] = useState<any>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCities(db:any) {
      const citiesCol = collection(db, 'emails');
      const citySnapshot = await getDocs(citiesCol); 
      if (citySnapshot) {
        setEmails(citySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          data: doc.data(),
      })))
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
      
    }
    getCities(db)
  },[])

return (
    <div  className='inbox'>{emails.map(({data:{description, recipients, subject, time} id}:dataBaseType) => (
          <MailRow key={id} recipients={recipients} time={time} subject={subject} description={description}/>
      ))}
</div>


// mailrow file

import {MailRowType } from "../pages/Inbox"
const MailRow = ({recipients, subject, description, time}) => {

  return (
    <div className='mailrow'>
 
       <h2>{recipients}</h2>      
       <h4>{subject}</h4>
       <p>{description}</p>
       <span>{time}</span>
    </div>
)
}

export default MailRow
```